# Exception: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection. With disabled LazyLoading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

Occasionally, I get a following exception:
"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection".

The reproduction of this exception is unstable and very hard to catch.

Generally, I get this exception when two or more requests are being sent simultaneously by browser.

An integration test was used running hundreds of threads simultaneously
with unique instances of DbContext and subsequent execution of model methods.
Though, this test didn't throw any exception and passed.

Exception is thrown at the first request to Db:

```
public IForumCategory GetCategoryById(int id)
{
    return Repository.ForumCategories.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
}
```

LazyLoading has been disabled and navigation properties are not being used.
"Includes" are also not used and are replaced by "joins".

Disposing DbContext:

```
public abstract class WebApiDependencyScope<TModelFactory> : IDependencyScope where TModelFactory : ModelFactory
{
    ...

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        ModelFactory.Dispose();
    }

    ...
}
```

DbContext is then disposed by ModelFactory so it can't be considered as an early DbContext disposing

**Updated info:**
DbContext created per request by AspNet WebApi Framework:

```
public override IDependencyScope BeginScope()       
{           
    ISiteRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory = new SiteAspNetRepositoryFactory(Config);
    GameModelFactory factory = new GameModelFactory(
     repositoryFactory, LocaleProvider, Config, Authenticate);

    Scope = new GameWebApiDependencyScope(factory);
    return Scope;
}
```

Comment: @Mr.Fahrenheit, it's so. DbContext is created per request in DependencyScope, then disposed by WebApi.

Comment: How are you making sure that each request is receiving its own DbContext instance?

Comment: @usr because AspNet WebApi is creating DependencyScope per request and then DependencyScope is creating one instance of DbContext and inject it into ModelFactory

Comment: @usr I'm added info to topic with code of DbContext instance creating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I can't understand it until the end, but maybe...

What happening:
Every time I create child scope and assign It for root scope. But every child scope is disposing when request ended. In this way root scope at this moment can have disposed scope and when it's trying create service from this scope I have this exception.

How and why root scope throw this particular exception I have no idea.

Now BeginScope looks:

```
public override IDependencyScope BeginScope()       
{           
    ISiteRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory = new SiteAspNetRepositoryFactory(Config);
    GameModelFactory factory = new GameModelFactory(
     repositoryFactory, LocaleProvider, Config, Authenticate);

    return new GameWebApiDependencyScope(factory);
}
```

And Root scope is initialized ones in Resolver constructor.
I may have fixed the problem, but this is not exactly, because exception is unstable.